# PECL install failed opcache

Tags: php, debian, pecl

I am having trouble installing zendopcache. When I am running

```
pecl install zendopcache-7.0.3
```

I am getting the following:

```
downloading zendopcache-7.0.3.tgz ...
Starting to download zendopcache-7.0.3.tgz (Unknown size)
....done: 3,582 bytes
Could not get contents of package "/tmp/pear/download/zendopcache-7.0.3.tgz". Invalid tgz file.
Download of "pecl/zendopcache" succeeded, but it is not a valid package archive
Error: cannot download "pecl/zendopcache"
Download failed
install failed
```

I have looked around for similar issues and I found some suggestion about adding -Z to the install command. This seems to only change the name of the requested file from zendopcache-7.0.3.tgz to zendopcache-7.0.3.tar but the output remains the same (yes, it still complains that a .tar is not a valid .tgz).

I am running Debian 7 Wheezy with PHP 5.4.4-14+deb7u14

I have seen similar issues reported but none had working answers.

Can someone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems there was a temporary issue with the pecl & pear servers. nevermind